# Не появляется тень у блока при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Почему то не появляется тень при прокрутке

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('header').toggleClass('scroll', $(this).scrollTop() > 63);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.scroll {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы в скрипте обращаетесь к тегу `header`, а стили прописали для класса `.header` - вот и не отрабатывает:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.header').toggleClass('scroll', $(this).scrollTop() > 63);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 63px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.scroll {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```